# Google maps API checking is element exists

Tags: google-maps-api-3, geocode

I'm calling google maps geocode and looping over the address_components struct and tring to output the city name. I'd like to store the postal_town as the city name but if it does not exist then use the administrative_area_level_2 instead.

The problem is that even if a postal_town is returned the administrative_area_level_2 is still being used. Can anybody see what i'm doing wrong?

```
for(var i=0, len=result.address_components.length; i<len; i++) {
                var ac = result.address_components[i];

                if(ac.types.indexOf("postal_town") >= 0){
                    state = $('#sharesparestepAddressCity').val(ac.long_name);
                }else if(ac.types.indexOf("administrative_area_level_2") >= 0){
                    state = $('#sharesparestepAddressCity').val(ac.long_name);   
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both exist, your code will return the last one found.  Add a `break` to stop processing when you find the one you want.

```
for(var i=0, len=result.address_components.length; i<len; i++) {
  var ac = result.address_components[i];
  if(ac.types.indexOf("postal_town") >= 0){
     state = $('#sharesparestepAddressCity').val(ac.long_name);
     break;
  } else if(ac.types.indexOf("administrative_area_level_2") >= 0){
     state = $('#sharesparestepAddressCity').val(ac.long_name);   
  }
}
```